# Azure Worker Role not working after upgrade to Azure Tools 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have updated my Azure project to use Azure Tools 2.0. Now, my worker role is always restarting before hitting the OnStart method.

My worker project references Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime 2.0

I have upgraded my Cloud Project throught properties and upgrade button to 2.0

But when I start the cloud project I can see this:

```
'WaWorkerHost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime\1.8.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll'
```

My Azure Compute Emulator is 2.0.

Any idea from where it comes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many operations I discovered that two projects in my solutions didn't got updated and were still bound to 1.8 instead of 2.0. :/

Comment: Thank you, that was also my problem. Seems that the Upgrade Tool for Azure Projects only performs the upgrade on the web/worker role projects in the solution. If there is an additional library Project that is used by the role projects and that also references the azure assemblies, it's neccessary to upgrade these references manually.